# Cyclic GraphQL Schema Not Working

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

I have like this:

```
//driverType.js
module.exports = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Driver',
  fields: () => ({
    homeTerminal: {
      type: TerminalType,
      resolve: resolver(User.HomeTerminal)
    }
  })
});
```

and this:

```
//terminalType.js
module.exports = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Terminal',
  fields: () => ({
    drivers: {
      type: new GraphQLList(DriverType),
      resolve: resolver(Terminal.Drivers)
    }
  })
});
```

I get the error:

> Error: Schema must contain unique named types but contains multiple
>   types named "Driver".

I found some posts that say that wrapping the fields in a function block will solve it, but as you can see I did that, and it didn't make a difference.

Thins kind of cyclic reference should be supported, yes? We can let the client will specify the desired depth.

What am I doing wrong?

As a workaround, I could remove `homeTerminal` from DriverType and flatten it with primitive fields, but that's rather inelegant.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with cycles, but without the rest of your schema code, it's impossible to tell what the problem is. It looks like you're somehow adding the Driver type twice, or you copy-pasted the type definition, but forgot to change 'name' somewhere.

Comment: If I remove ```drivers``` from ```TerminalType ``` the error goes away. If I remove ```homeTerminal``` from ```DriverType``` it does not go away. I suppose that's a clue.

Comment: There is definitely only one ```GraphQLObjectType``` with name of "Driver".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. In `terminalType.js` I had:

`import DriverType from './DriverType';`

Should be:

`import DriverType from './driverType';`

Lower case "d" is correct.

**UPDATE**

Here's what I think is happening. Nodejs caches imports. So importing the same file multiple times always returns the same instance. However, I believe that, while `import` is *not* case-sensitive caching *is*. So calling with a different case on the filename returns a new and different instance.

Comment: You didn't explain how your solution in the answer relates to or solves the problem / error in the question. Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: @TimScott: That sounds like a bug in Node that should be fixed!

Comment: @helfer: I'm new to node. I spent probably 5 hours on this, chasing all kinds of false leads. It turns our this a well known bug for 2 years with an unmerged PR. Unbelievable. I can't help but ask myself whether node is the community for me. https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/6829